# Is mixing react-bootstrap and plain bootstrap a bad idea

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am working on a large team project that has react-bootstrap 1.0.0 as well as bootstrap 4.3.1's css+js. Some developers prefer using react-bootstrap components, while others prefer styling elements with bootstrap classes. So we've ended up with two different styles of code:

```
<ListGroup>
  <ListGroup.Item>
    Cras justo odio
  </ListGroup.Item>
```

vs.

```
<ul className="list-group">
  <li className="list-group-item">
    Cras justo odio
  </li>
```

What obstacles might we encounter by continuing this way?

One issue I see might be upgrading react-bootstrap or bootstrap in the future. Since react-bootstrap depends on bootstrap, upgrading one would require upgrading the other at the same time. This means following two migration strategies at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer could vary depending on who you ask, but I would suspect a large majority to agree that it is a bad idea. There really is no such thing as "just being inconsistent." A lot of the reasons why this should be avoided boils down to the fact that something, somewhere is inconsistent. Here are a few examples:

- **Cross-Library Interactions** - The biggest reason in my opinion is that Bootstrap is a DOM-manipulating JavaScript Framework, and React is a JavaScript UI Library. In order words, it's possible for Bootstrap to unexpected modify React components, resulting in unintended side effects. Imagine using jQuery to manipulate your React components. With Bootstrap, that's effectively what you're doing. React Bootstrap was built to replicate Bootstrap with the JS implementation was rebuilt from scratch, but reuses class names that can be targetted by the core BS JS.
- **Speed/Performance** - By including both Bootstrap and React Bootstrap, you have two dependencies that serve the exact same purpose. Regardless of how small it may be, you can save a few extra bytes by dropping one of them.
- **Maintainability** - If your application needs to be updated, you either need track down someone with that particular expertise or have someone learn that style anyway. Even if all your developers are familiar with both styles, it gets confusing having to switch between two different mindsets.
- **Expectability** - Which parts of your application uses which style? How do you know? How would a developer know when they need to switch styles? Rather than have it be a coin toss on what to use when, it's easier for everyone if the entire application was consistent.
- **Hiring/Training** - In any team, let alone a large one, people come and go. So should you ever lose a developer and need to replace them, this is an extra factor to consider, whether it be in the hiring process itself or (more likely) part of the training.

Answer (score 4):

Your React-Bootstrap components and your JSX with Bootstrap classes will be styled by the same CSS file. RB doesn't include *any* of its own styles and requires you to use Bootstrap's CSS. No double migration necessary there. If you update or replace a stylesheet it will affect both of your code blocks.

React-Bootstrap also doesn't use Bootstrap's JavaScript, but its own reimplementation. That means attaching Bootstrap's JS shouldn't affect the function of RB components and that it would be necessary if you wanted to use Bootstrap's JavaScript behaviors in the second version of your code.

Info here:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/